# make android application performance better

Tags: android

my android application performance is low, it takes a long startup time. i have 5 buttons, one imageview, 3 textView, 2 editText and one listView initialized in onCreate() method. Is large number of ui object the reason for slow startup?? Is there any fault in manifest.xml??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.ars.application"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/lightvasicon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name=".LightVas"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: we have no idea why it takes so long without posting code. Inflating the imageviews COULD be the culprit but we can only guess.

Comment: Do you have some network job or database query in onCreate() ? If so, you may want to populate your listview with an ASyncTask.

Comment: by taking the allocation track, i got the memory eater as "android.app.ApplicationContext$SharedPreferencesImpl writeFileLocked ApplicationContext.java    2807    false"     How can i avoid memory leak caused by this???

Comment: please, answer the questions if you want answers. The problem may not be allocation at that point. Any db or network job at activity creation ? Maybe you could post the code of onCreate which causes problem.

Comment: i have network jobs in onStart(). i implemented all the views of my application in onCreate(). then did some request to the network in onstart()

Comment: anybody know the significance of this message  11-08 18:03:37.614: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(12128): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.260MB for 12226-byte allocation ???

Comment: network jobs in onStart or onCreate are likely to block the start of the application, unless you use a background thread to do it (with ASyncTask for example). Heap has to be extended probably because you store data in memory during your network request (in something like a ByteArray). You should stream your file directly to the sd if possible).

Comment: @Rorist  i checked the heap and allocation tracker. the maximum memory is 5mb. a lot of objects are created while parsing an xml. Now i am using in debugging mode in my htc device's phone memery. if i use in sd card, can i improve the performance???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generic performance advice:

In most cases you shouldn't try to guess what is causing performance problems as intuition is often wrong. If you knew the cause of slow code, you wouldn't have written it slow in the first place!

1. Use [the profiler](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html) to work out where your performance problems are.
2. Optimize just the slow parts. Keep a copy of your traces and compare them after making a change, so you know whether you're heading in the right direction or not.
3. Make your own simple timing method to verify your results, this will make sure that trace recording itself is not causing performance issues in a different place.

Comment: i inspected application's low performance area using track analyzer. i got "android.app.ApplicationContext$SharedPreferencesImpl writeFileLocked ApplicationContext.java 2807 false" is a memory eater. How can i avoid this??

Comment: Those tips are very good only if one has a clue about Java in general. If the base knowledge is missing nothing will help other than learning Java.

Comment: @asifkt - Don't worry too much about the memory for now, focus on the time spent in each method. Start with the longest running methods, then drill down into the function calls which are eating the time. @Octavian, you're right of course, but profiling is still useful, it can teach beginners how to write fast programs.